# Execute PHP script when someone requested a certain file in another Folder

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, php, web-hosting

I am building a WebHosting service. Users can create a Account and upload Files with FTP and access them by visiting username.mywebsite.com (just an example). I would like to record the number of visits any file in the Folder of my User has. So I would like to execute a PHP Script when any file in that Folder is visited. But I don't want to change the HTML/PHP files my User uploaded. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

- Max

Comment: Parse the access log? Or better yet, use a already existing web statistics software that does that for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the answer in this one: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/32964

Basically, do something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

> make script.php run your code and afterwards redirects using the filename variable you passed to it. ($_GET['filename'])